# Finding the CDF of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value

Your statistics teacher challenges you to write a mathematics paper, which depending on your time spent, will earn you a cash reward. You're given the paper and a candle stands on the table in front of you. The life span $X$, in minutes, of the candle is a continuous random variable with a uniform distribution on $(0, 60)$. You must leave after $\frac{1}{2}$ an hour has been spent writing the paper or as soon as the candle burns out, whichever of these happens first. The teacher gives you a cash reward $M$ equal to *half* the amount of time the candle was lit. Find the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $M$ and determine the expected value $E[M]$.

My attempt:

By inspection $M = \frac{X}{2}$.

I think cdf of $M$ is of the form:

$$F(m)= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      0 & \mbox{if } x < 0 \\
      2x = m &  \mbox{if } 0 \leq x < 60 \\
      1 & \mbox{if } 60 \leq x  
      \end{array}
\right.$$

As for $E(M)$, we have

$$E(M) = \int_{0}^{60} m \cdot F'(m) \,dm = \int_{0}^{60} m \,dm = 1800$$

Is this correct? My work above seems lacking and I am not sure if I did it correctly. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: I think $M$ is equal to half the time from the beginning to when you leave (i.e. doesn't include the time the candle was lit after you leave). In this case, the answer would be different.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Hmm. So would the last case in the piecewise cdf be $0$?

Comment: No - the limit of a CDF should be $1$. Also, what you have isn't right because a CDF is always non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lifespan of the candle is $X\sim \mathscr {Unif}(0, 60)$ then your reward is $M=\frac 1 2 \min(30, X)=15\cdot \mathbb I(60>X>30)+\frac 1 2 X\cdot \mathbb I(0<X<30)$. I means it is a 1 if the criteria inside is satisfied and a 0 if it is not satisfied. So this is a convenient way of writing a binary outcome. It just means if X is between 30 and 60, M is 15, and if X is between 0 and 30, M is X/2.

- The expected value of this is $$\begin{align}E(M)&=15\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{60}\Bbb I(30<x<60)dx+\frac 1 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{60}\Bbb I(0<x<30)dx\\[1ex]&=15\int_{30}^{60}\frac {1}{60}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{30}\frac{x}{60}dx\\[1ex]&=\frac{15}{2}+\frac{1}{240}(30)^2\\[1ex]&=\frac{45}{4}\\[1ex]&=11.25\end{align}$$

Or, if you don't want to think about "I", you see that M is 15 with probability 1/2 and 1/2X with probability 1/2. Then $E(M)~{=15\, P(M=15)+\int_0^{30} (1/2)xf(x)dx\\=7.5+\int_0^{30}\frac 1 2x\frac{1}{60}dx\\~\vdots}$

- M has pmf $P(M=15)=\frac 1 2$ and a pdf of $f(M)=\frac 1{30}$ for 0<M<15 and $f(M)=0$ otherwise.

  - Half of $M$'s probability mass is uniformly distributed over $[0..15)$ and half of the probability mass occurs at $15$.

Thus it has cdf

$$F(m)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }& ~~~~~~~m<0\\\frac{m}{30}&\text{if }&0\le m<15\\1&\text{if }&15\le m\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with the notation $\mathbb{I}$. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explaining. However, why exactly is the reward $15$ if $30 < X < 60$? Is it not that the reward given for half the time spent?

Comment: I think you must stop writing the paper as soon as 30 minutes are up, so you don't actually get money for if the candle runs longer than 30 minutes. @Kraftsman

Comment: If the candle lasts longer than 30 minutes, you still only receive a reward of $15$ because you left *at* the 30 minute mark.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Kemp Ah, that is why. Quite a tricky problem, but thank you.

Comment: @Stacker Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$M=\tfrac 12\min(X,30)$ where $X\sim\mathcal U[0..60]$

Half of the probability mass of $M$ will be distributed uniformly over $[0..15)$ while half will be massed at the point of $15$.

Therefore $F_{\small M}(m)= (m/30)\mathbf 1_{m\in[0..15)}+\mathbf 1_{15\leqslant m}$

$\therefore \mathsf E(M) ~{=\int_0^\infty 1-F_{\small M}(m)\,\mathrm d m\\= \int_0^{15} 1-m/30\,\mathrm d m\\=15-15^2/60\\=15(3/4)\\=11.25}$